Error When Displaying Image Through customtkinter (pyimage26)
Within my code script I have a window open up that should display a image of a creeper head. Whenever I try running the code, I get this error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1967, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "/Users/*me*/Desktop/Python/Computer Science 20 Stuff/Cookie Clicker Game/main.py", line 380, in info_button_callback
    new_window()
  File "/Users/*me*/Desktop/Python/Computer Science 20 Stuff/Cookie Clicker Game/main.py", line 143, in new_window
    creeper_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_label.py", line 104, in __init__
    self._update_image()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_label.py", line 141, in _update_image
    self._label.configure(image=self._image.create_scaled_photo_image(self._get_widget_scaling(),
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1721, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1711, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage26" doesn't exist

I have verified that it is within the same file path as the python file, I have changed the image with another image i was able to load in for a different purpose within my code, and I have checked the file extension and it is appropriate.
Code (short form):
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image


creeper_bg = customtkinter.CTkImage(
    dark_image=Image.open("creeper_bg.png"), size=(70, 70))

def main_loop():
    * Main stuff here*
    def back_right_button_callback():
        * back_right_button_callback stuff here *
        def info_button_callback():
            info_window = customtkinter.CTk()

            w = 300
            h = 200
            ws = info_window.winfo_screenwidth()
            hs = info_window.winfo_screenheight()
            x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
            y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
            info_window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
            info_window.resizable(False, False)

            creeper_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
                info_window, width=70, height=70, image=creeper_bg, text="", corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent", bg_color="transparent")
            creeper_label.place(x=10, y=100, anchor="w")

            info_window.mainloop()



        info_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(main, image=info_bg, text="", width=40, height=40, fg_color="transparent", bg_color="transparent", corner_radius=0, border_width=0, border_spacing=0, hover=True, hover_color="#868686", command=info_button_callback)
        info_button.place(x=46, y=576, anchor="w")


Paste Bin: https://pastebin.com/WxW4ybKA


You're creating the image before you actually initialize CTk.  Assuming that this works similarly to plain Tk, this results in an entirely separate instance of the GUI environment being created for you, containing nothing but that image.  The instance that you actually created yourself simply cannot access it.

@jasonharper so how would I fix my code?

maybe create creeper_bg = customtkinter.CTkImage() after customtkinter.CTk()

why do you have nested functions? It seams strange and unreadable.

@furas didn't work sadly, and honestly i don't know another way so i nested them

maybe put functions in normal way - one after another. see more PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

i'm not sure but normal tkitner had problem with images assigned to local variable (in function) because garbage colector removed it - and this needed to assign image to global variable or to other class - ie. creeper_label.my_image = image

error shows problem with image inside function new_window() but I don't see this function in your question, nor in code on pastebin.

The error is mostly caused by multiple instances of Tk (which is what CTk inherits). It is better to provide a [mre] instead of linked code.

@jasonharper Creating instance of CTkImage will not create CTk() implicitly.

Hey everyone, figured out what was wrong, i just needed for info_window to be info_window = customtkinter.CTkToplevel() instead of info_window = customtkinter.CTk()

figured out what was wrong, i just needed for info_window to be info_window = customtkinter.CTkToplevel() instead of info_window = customtkinter.CTk()
